# I just bought an additional site license for MSM but don't want to upgrade EE, what can I do?

Tags: expressionengine

It seems that the only way to add an additional site to an MSM install is to upgrade the MSM module, which coincidentally requires one to upgrade the main EE install files in tandem. Is there a way around this?

It's not feasible at this time to upgrade the clients sites, but we need to add an additional site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this, but it is not officially supported. To update the number of sites your MSM is licensed for, download the new zip after making your purchase and then ONLY replace one file.

system > expressionengine > libraries > Sites.php

This file contains a hashed/encrypted value for the number of sites you may install.